# How do I get appendix titles in the same style as chapter titles?

Tags: formatting, chapters, appendices

I'm using the book class and the following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\large}
\chapterfont{}
\sectionfont{}
\subsectionfont{}
\subsubsectionfont{\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}\bfseries}
```

My chapter titles look like this:

[image: sssss]

Now, I'd like to have appendices follow the same style, with "Chapter" replaced by "Appendix" and the number replaced by a letter. I'm currently using the following code at the beginning of each appendix:

```
\chapter*{Appendix A:\\Mathematica correlation code}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A: Mathematica correlation code}
```

However, this doesn't achieve the desired result, since it removes the "Chapter *N*" line altogether, raises the appendix title to where the removed line used to be and writes "Appendix A" in the same font size as the appendix title:

[image]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}

% BASE PACKAGES
    % symbol packages
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage{mathrsfs}
        \usepackage{esvect}
        \usepackage{latexsym}
        \usepackage{mathtools}
    % graphics packages
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{epstopdf}
        \DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `basename #1 .tif`.png}
        \usepackage{float}
        \usepackage{subfig}

% PAGE LAYOUT
    % base packages
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{wasysym}
        \usepackage[cam,letter,center]{crop}
    % page margins
        \textheight 22.5cm
        \topmargin -0.5in
        \usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
    % page headers
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
        \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
        \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
        \fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\leftmark}

% FONTS
    % base packages
        \usepackage{amsfonts}
        \usepackage{mathspec}
    % font controls
        \setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Calluna}
        \setsansfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Calluna}
        \setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Arabic=Regular,Uppercase=Italic,Lowercase=Italic,Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}]{Calluna}
        \setmonofont[Ligatures={NoRequired,NoCommon,NoContextual},Numbers={Lining,Monospaced},Scale=0.8]{Courier New Bold}
    % line height
        \linespread{1.05}
    % non-italic Greek letters
        \usepackage{textgreek}

% TITLES
    % title styles
        \usepackage{sectsty}
        \allsectionsfont{\large}
        \chapterfont{}
        \sectionfont{}
        \subsectionfont{}
        \subsubsectionfont{\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}\bfseries}
    % title spacing
        \makeatletter
        \def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}{\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}
        \def\section@cntformat{\thesection.\quad}
        \def\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\quad}
        \makeatother
        \usepackage{titlesec}
        \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

% TABLE OF CONTENTS
    % base packages
        \usepackage{titletoc}
    % formatting
        \titlecontents{chapter}[2.4em]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2em}}{}{\titlerule*[0.73pc]{ .}\contentspage}
        \titlecontents{section}[4.8em]{\addvspace{0pc}}{\contentslabel{3em}}{}{\titlerule*[0.73pc]{ .}\contentspage}
        \titlecontents{subsection}[7.2em]{\addvspace{0pc}}{\contentslabel{3.5em}}{}{\titlerule*[0.73pc]{ .}\contentspage}

% DUMMY TEXT
    % lipsum
        \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}\sloppy

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Preliminary concepts}

\lipsum

\chapter*{Appendix A:\\Mathematica correlation code}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A: Mathematica correlation code}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  oneside=on,
  chapterprefix=on,
  appendixprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Preliminary concepts}
\lipsum

\appendix
\chapter{Mathematica correlation code}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You have not provided a compilable MWE so we don't even know what class you are using.

In the standard classes the `\appendix` command before your appendices code does what you want.

So, for example

```
...
\lipsum
\appendix
\chapter{Mathematica correlation code}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

But if that does not work for you then the `appendix` package is probably your saviour; read the manual (`> texdoc appendix`).

Comment: Apologies, you're right. I will edit my question to include more information. I'll also have a look at that package.